# Redirect Public IP to Subfolder Apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I would like to redirect a public ip so that it goes to a specific folder within my apache web server. How can this be done. Also if I create another sub directory what configs would I have to do to my .htaccess file so that another public ip can access the new sub directory? If there is a better way to do this please suggest such thanks.

Below is what I have tried however I want to change the domain to the public ip address instead.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder/ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder/$1 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ igovtt/index.php [L]
Options -Indexes
```

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. Can you be more specific.. give an example so that we can understand what you really want.

Comment: @kums I updated the question with some of what I tried before